# Ruby on Rails - wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def delete_homework
   Homework.all(:conditions => {:teacher => params.require(:teacher) })

   redirect_to :back
end
```

This is my controller

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="card blue-grey lighten-2">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <span class="card-title">Delete Homework</span>
        <form action="/welcome/delete_homework">
          <input type="text" name="teacher" placeholder="Teacher Name">
          <input class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the HTML side.

When I try this, ruby gives
ArgumentError in WelcomeController#delete_homework
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

what's wrong? please help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: How you define route for `delete_homework` action?

Comment: The `all(:conditions =>...)` syntax was used in Rails up to version `2.3` and doesn't work anymore in newer versions. Whatever book oder tutorial you found with a code example with that syntax - it is outdated for at least 5 years...

Comment: @ashvin 
  `Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index_array'
  get 'welcome/index_hash'
  get 'welcome/index_db'
  get 'welcome/create_homework'
  get 'welcome/delete_homework'
  get 'welcome/index_manage'`

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
Homework.all( your_conditions )
```

to:

```
Homework.where( your_conditions )
```

The `all` method can't take any parameters. It should only be used when you simply want to grab all the records of a given model from the database.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Homework.where(:teacher => params[:teacher])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping a noob... one more question. What is the code to delete a db with the param teacher?

Comment: `homeworks = Homework.where(:teacher => params[:teacher])`  `homeworks.delete_all`